# Unable to set Firefox Default Program Associations

Tags: windows-7, firefox

All of a sudden after months of working properly, I am unable to open hotlinks from within Outlook using my default browser Firefox. If I change Chrome to be the default browser (using Chrome settings), then clicking links opens a new tab in Chrome. If I change Firefox back to default browser, clicking links doesn't work anymore.

I then tried to change the default OS program associations, however everything is greyed out, even if I click the Select All checkbox:
[image]

If I click that blue mozilla link in the image above, nothing happens as well.

Event Log shows no warnings or messages anywhere.

I think somehow the internal path to firefox.exe is probably messed up?

Comment: Tried uninstalling and then reinstalling Firefox?

Comment: I was trying to avoid that in case I had to re-install all my plugins/bookmarks, but it worked (plugins/bookmarks included)!

Comment: Nice! glad to hear that.

Comment: I don't know how to go from here. Do you want to submit this as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: No probs. As I suggested a basic idea, I don't want to post it as an answer although it might qualify as an "answer" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by user "w32sh" in the comments, uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox fixed the problem.